# security websocket with nodejs php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, redis

I'm developing an auction website where user has to login before bid.
The website is realised in php and the main data (users, auction etc) are stored in mysql.
To realize a real-time system I use node.js to develop a websocket (i used socket.io) where i catch bids data from redis. Making control with php if the user is logged is very simple of course but I want to make sure my system controlling if the request was made by a logged users also in nodejs. How can i do it? passing users data every socket request is not sure and this mean that every time I have to make a query to mysql to check if the user exists (not really a good practice) and this i think will slow my system. Do you have some idea?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to authorize the user once after creating a new connection. Such an send authorization cookies after connection. After checking the cookies you can bind the current connection to the user. For greater security you can send in response to client a small random key dependent on ip addresses. This key will be sent with each request. You do not need to make an additional mysql request to check it out.

Comment: but the cookies works for differents ports? because i have the website under http://www.example.com/ and the websocket under http://www.example.com:8888, is it posibile with nodejs to catch the cookies from the first? and normally authorizations with cookie aren't very safe?

Comment: You can get auth cookie with javascript from document.cookie and send it with socket.io first message directly.